# Clojure recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure, split, concatenation

As a Clojure newbie, I'm bothered with this small problem:

I would like to iterate through a sequence and execute a `split`, and then a `str` (concatenation) function over the sequence elements.

Here is my sequence:

```
(("2.660.784") ("2.944.552") ("44.858.797"))
```

What I want to get is something like this:

```
("2660784" "2944552" "44858797")
```

And this is my attempt of creating recursive solution for my problem:

```
(defn old 
      [squence]
      (let [size (count squence)]
        (loop [counter 1]
          (if (<= counter size)
            (apply str (clojure.string/split 
                   (first (first squence))
                   #"\b\.\b"
                   ))
            (old (rest squence)))
          )))
```

And of course, this is not a solution because it applies `split` and `str` only to one element, but I would like to repeat this for each element in `squence`. The `squence` is product of some other function in my project.

I'm definitely missing something so please help me out with this one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to write it is with `replace`, rather than `split`/`str`. And once you've written a function that can do this transformation on a single string, you can use `map` or `for` to do it to a sequence of strings. Here I had to destructure a bit, since for whatever reason  each element of your sequence is itself another sequence; I just pulled out the first element.

```
(for [[s] '(("2.660.784") ("2.944.552") ("44.858.797"))]
  (clojure.string/replace s #"\b\.\b" ""))
```

Comment: Note that in clojure one should prefer vectors over quoted lists when applicable.

Comment: Hi,first of all thanks for reply. The reason why are these strings in separated lists (within a list) is that they are product of mine clojure/enlive selector steps functions, therefore, I can't mess with it.  I'am doing this, so I could parse them in to numbers (integers to be exact), basically on resulting collection I would like to apply Java Integer.parse ("string") method. Am I on right track, or is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar: Performance. Vectors are arrays, lists are linked lists. Arrays are generally faster except for when it comes to adding or removing items.

Answer (score 3):

```
user=> (defn reject-char-from-string
  [ch sequence]
  (map #(apply str (replace {ch nil} (first %))) sequence))
#'user/reject-char-from-string
user=> (reject-char-from-string \. '(("2.660.784") ("2.944.552") ("44.858.797"))
)
("2660784" "2944552" "44858797")
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?

```
=> (flatten '(("2.660.784") ("2.944.552") ("44.858.797")))
("2.660.784" "2.944.552" "44.858.797")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it as simple as this?

```
(def data '(("2.660.784") ("2.944.552") ("44.858.797")))
(require '[clojure.string :as string])
(map #(string/replace (first %1) "." "") data)
;=> ("2660784" "2944552" "44858797")
```

Comment: Pretty much, and after I have to convert the strings into numbers (parsing with Java's integer.parse method). Is there some more elegant solution?

Comment: How about this? (map #(-> (first %1) (string/replace "." "") (Integer/parseInt)) data)